How can I move a stop loss to breakeven when it reaches a $50 profit without selling any portion of my position?
Have tried many things. Nothing seems to work... this example is from ChatGPT I don't want to sell 50% of my position when profit target is reached. I want to keep my position as is but with a new stop loss at breakeven
//@version=5
strategy("108 O/C Plot Strat SHA", overlay=true, default_qty_type=strategy.contracts, default_qty_value=1)

// User inputs for take profit and stop loss
tp1 = input.float(125, step=5, title="Take Profit 1 Long")
tp2 = input.float(165, step=5, title="Take Profit 2 Long")
sl2 = input.float(200, step=5, title="Stop Loss Long")

tp1S = input.float(185, step=5, title="Take Profit 1 Short")
tp2S = input.float(225, step=5, title="Take Profit 2 Short")
sl2S = input.float(200, step=5, title="Stop Loss Short")

breakEvenProfit = 50 // Profit threshold to move stop loss to break even

// Dummy trading logic for demonstration purposes
// Replace this with your actual trading conditions
longCondition = ta.crossover(close, ta.sma(close, 14))
shortCondition = ta.crossunder(close, ta.sma(close, 14))

var float entryPrice = na
var float stopLossPrice = na

if (longCondition)
    entryPrice := close
    stopLossPrice := close - sl2
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if (shortCondition)
    entryPrice := close
    stopLossPrice := close + sl2S
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

// Monitor open profit and adjust stop loss to break even if the profit threshold is reached
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    profit = strategy.position_avg_price - close
    if (profit >= breakEvenProfit)
        stopLossPrice := entryPrice
        strategy.exit("Break Even Exit", "Long", stop=stopLossPrice)

if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    profit = close - strategy.position_avg_price
    if (profit >= breakEvenProfit)
        stopLossPrice := entryPrice
        strategy.exit("Break Even Exit", "Short", stop=stopLossPrice)

// Exit conditions based on take profit and stop loss
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("TP1/SL", from_entry="Long", limit=entryPrice + tp1, stop=stopLossPrice)

if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.exit("TP1/SL", from_entry="Short", limit=entryPrice - tp1S, stop=stopLossPrice)


AI-generated code is inconsistent, buggy, and unreliable. Artificial Intelligence is very useful in many aspects, but it encodes Pinescript very poorly (for now...).
Consequently, TradingView and the PineCoders community have decided to not provide support to fix GPT-related code.
